# Limit of sum of natural logarithms with expo

Tags: limits, summation, logarithms

Could you give me some hint or further advice me about the papers that can solve this solution

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\log(p+(1-p)e^{ab(1-\frac{b(1-(bc)^{i})}{1-bc})-(bc)^ic})}$

assuming that bc < 1 and b $\in$ (0,1).

In my work, I find by using lower bound and upper bound of them, but I want to find the general form of this term if it could be ? 
Would you give me some advice or hint ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}A_i=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ by [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). So, the answer must be $$\log\left(p+(1-p)e^{ab\big(1-b/(1-bc)\big)}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much, for your answer, I will study Stolz-Cesaro. Thank a lot